# Signal Processing and Audio Beat Detection

Tags: audio, signals, processing, detection

I am trying to do some work with basic Beat Detection (in both C and/or Java) by following the guide from [GameDev.net](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/index.html).  I understand the logic behind the implementation of the algorithms, however I am confused as to how one would get the "sound amplitude" data for the left and right channels of a song (i.e. mp3 or wav).

For example, he starts with the following assumption:

> In this model we will detect sound energy variations by computing the average sound energy of the signal and comparing it to the instant sound energy. Lets say we are working in stereo mode with two lists of values : (an) and (bn). (an) contains the list of sound amplitude values captured every Te seconds for the left channel, (bn) the list of sound amplitude values captured every Te seconds for the right channel.

He then proceeds to manipulate `an` and `bn` using his following algorithms.  I am wondering how one would do the Signal Processing necessary to get `an` and `bn` every `Te` seconds for both channels, such that I can begin to follow his guide and mess around with some simple Beat Detection in songs.

Answer (score 1):

An uncompressed audio file (a .wav or.aiff for example) is for the most part a long array of samples. Each sample consists of the amplitude at a given point in time. When music is recorded, many of these amplitude samples are taken each second. 
For stereo (2-channel) audio files, the samples in the array usually alternate channels: [sample1 left, sample1 right, sample2 left, sample2 right, etc...].

Most audio parsing libraries will already have a way of returning the samples separately for each channel.

Once you have the sample array for each channel, it is easy to find the samples for a particular second, as long as you know the sample rate, or number of samples per second. For example, if the sample rate for your file is 44100 samples per second, and you want to capture the samples in *n* th second, you would use the part of your vector that is between (*n* *  44100 ) and ((*n* + 1) * 44100).